# print URL of current page in specDone in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am trying to print the current URL of the page on which tests were done in specDone in protractor like this

```
   specDone(result){
        browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then((browserURL) =>{                     
              console.log("urlinside", browserURL);
        })
```

but all that it prints after running the test is "urlinside data". I see it opens the browser and runs correctly. My goal is to print the URL in case a test fails

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
specDone(result) {
        console.log('Spec has finished.');

        if (!result.failedExpectations || result.failedExpectations.length <= 0) {

            browser.getCurrentUrl().then((url) => {
                console.log(`Test failed current url is ${url}`);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: since it works on my env, and its a common listner. please describe "didnt work"

Comment: I had put this in config.ts and I see that it prints `console.log('Spec has finished.');` and just exits out after that. Anything i try to print before browser.getCurrentUrl also gets printed - but does not print "test failed..."

Comment: using jasmine, you have to define a custom reporter example: https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html